# Problems sending a Vue.JS prop to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, vue.js

I'm working on a project that uses Vue.JS. I have a component that includes a button, text and a slot that allows me to insert more components inside. This component gets some props.

When I press the button, using the onclick, I want to send a prop (an id) to a JavaScript function. When this happens, the div that has that id will hide or show (using the toggle() function of JQuery). This happens if I specify the id in the code, but it doesn't work if I use the prop value that has the same value. Here is the code I use:

Those are the props:

```
props: {'obraName': String, 'idValue': String},
```

This is the template of the component where is the button, and with the onclick, I execute the JavaScript's function sending the prop as a parameter:

```
<div :style="style">
      <label :style="text">{{obraName}}</label>
      <!-- If I change this.idValue with a number, it works -->
      <button onclick='toggleListShow(this.idValue)'>x</button> 
      <div :style="text"><slot></slot></div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript function, using JQuery:

```
function toggleListShow(id) {
    $('#obra' + id + " div").toggle()
}
```

Finally, I declare the component with a PHP echo. I put other components inside the slot and, later, I close it. Here I declare the id (which will be obra + id of the obra), and the prop id-value (which is only the id of the obra):

```
echo "<obra obra-name=".$obra['name']." id=".'obra'.$obra['id']." id-value=".$obra['id'].">";
```

I have spent some hours trying to solve this, and I'd be really thankful if you could help me to find the error that's not allowing me to send the idValue prop (in the PHP is called id-value) to my JavaScript function.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also new to vuejs .so i'm not sure about the solution. but try like this  <button @click='toggleListShow(idValue)'>x</button>

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering so fast. That should be a good idea, but now, when I try it, I receive this: `TypeError: toggleListShow is not a function. (In 'toggleListShow(idValue)', 'toggleListShow' is undefined)`. The function toggleListShow(id) is declared in a JavaScript file.

Comment: is the   toggleListShow   function is in inside vue methods ?

Comment: No, it's not. The function toogleListShow() is in a JavaScript file called app.js. The components are declared in a JavaScript file called components.js.

Comment: I'll suggest you print some info in `toggleListShow` to make sure you do get the `id` and `$('#obra' + id + " div")` does exists and is exactly the element you wanna toggle. So, try `console.log(id, $('#obra' + id + " div").length, $('#obra' + id + " div").html());` in `toggleListShow`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I solved the problem. In my component, I was asking for a function in a JS document, inserted in the HTML. I added toogleListShow() in the methods of the Vue component, and then I was able to call him. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<div :style="style">
  <label :style="text">{{obraName}}</label>
  <button @click="toggleListShow(idValue)">x</button> 
  <div :style="text"><slot></slot></div>
</div>
```

When you're in the template section, you don't need to use "this".

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: That haven't solved my problem tho, I explained why on the comments. ^^